# <ReferenceError: todos is not defined> Javascript and Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I got a little problem with my angular app. I wrote the code in Typescript 
" https://jsfiddle.net/jump3r/7xm96dzt/ "

```
MainCtrl.prototype.addTodo = function () {
    var newTodo = this.$scope.newTodo.trim();
    if (newTodo.length < 10) {
        alert("The input must be longer then 10 signs!");
    }
    this.todos.push(new TodoItem(newTodo, false));
    this.$scope.newTodo = "";
    console.log(todos.length);
};
```

and then I created a .js file from the .ts file " https://jsfiddle.net/jump3r/v529h33y/ ".

My console said that todos isn't defined. can someone help me please.

If someone is wondering this is my HTML file https://jsfiddle.net/jump3r/d2z6agsy/ .

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle has `todos.push(new TodoItem(newTodo, false));` and not `this.todos`

Comment: What should I write then?

Comment: Did you try what you have above? this.todo and refresh the cache?

Comment: well now I dont get any error but there aren't any todos in the list, which should appear when I type in the input

Comment: Maybe an idea to put the script and html together in a [mcve]

Comment: Well now I have an another problem with my app. I don't have any errors now, but the app doesn't work properly. When I set a breakpoint in the addTodo(), I can see the todos are created and stored in todos[], but there is no output on the web app.